# Multiple Email Branding in our ISV service

Tags: administration, isv

I would like to have two different email branding to our ISV service.
And have two separate service registration forms - each one will have different email branding. Is that possible?

In our trial org I saw that you can create multiple email sets (branding) and you can create new source organizations with different email sets.

After I provision the new template ID with SalesForce I am not sure how can I direct it with the registration form?